# most efficient way to update pandas dataframe when index not match

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updates

I have two pandas DataFrames and I want to update one with the other...
But I cannot be sure that the indexes match. (so it is a problem to use **DataFrame.update** !)

exmaple:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([('path1', 0, 0, 0),
                    ('path2', 0, 0, 0),
                    ('path3', 0, 0, 0),
                    ('path4', 0, 0, 0),],
                  columns=['path', 'class', 'manual', 'conf'],
                  index = [1,2,3,4])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([('path1', 1, 0, 0),
                    ('path2', 0, 1, 0),
                    ('path3', 0, 0, 1),
                    ('path5', 1, 1, 0),
                    ('path6', 1, 1, 0),],
                  columns=['path', 'class', 'manual', 'conf'],
                  index = [10,11,12,13,14])
```

The desired outcome:

```
update_annotations(df1, df2)

    path  class  manual  conf
1  path1      1       0     0
2  path2      0       1     0
3  path3      0       0     1
4  path4      0       0     0
```

df1.update(df2) can be risky, as the indexes of these dataframes may not match. what is the safest way and most efficient to do so ?

Comment: set path column as index then update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Quick and Dirty

```
df1[['path']].merge(df2, 'left')

    path  class  manual  conf
0  path1    1.0     0.0   0.0
1  path2    0.0     1.0   0.0
2  path3    0.0     0.0   1.0
3  path4    NaN     NaN   NaN
```

---

#### Less quick and less dirty

```
df1[['path']].merge(df2, 'left').fillna(0).astype(df1.dtypes)

    path  class  manual  conf
0  path1      1       0     0
1  path2      0       1     0
2  path3      0       0     1
3  path4      0       0     0
```

---

#### Pedantic

Filling in `NaN` with `df1`

```
df1[['path']].merge(df2, 'left').fillna({**df1}).astype(df1.dtypes)

    path  class  manual  conf
0  path1      1       0     0
1  path2      0       1     0
2  path3      0       0     1
3  path4      0       0     0
```

#### Per [Chris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55634069/most-efficient-way-to-update-pandas-dataframe-when-index-not-match#comment97959500_55634069)

```
df1.set_index('path').assign(**df2.set_index('path')).reset_index()

    path  class  manual  conf
0  path1    1.0     0.0   0.0
1  path2    0.0     1.0   0.0
2  path3    0.0     0.0   1.0
3  path4    NaN     NaN   NaN
```

---

#### Preserve the index

Since order is guaranteed to be the same, we can just use `set_index`

```
df1[['path']].merge(df2, 'left').fillna({**df1}).astype(df1.dtypes).set_index(df1.index)

    path  class  manual  conf
1  path1      1       0     0
2  path2      0       1     0
3  path3      0       0     1
4  path4      0       0     0
```

Comment: Thanks!   well, I need order and original indexing guaranteed, so I guess The forth solution is the best.  I did not know that you can do .fillna({**df1}) - this is really cool.   I tried the first 2 before, and they do not pass some of my tests (I dont want to fill with 0).

Comment: What actually worked for me:  putting the set_index before the fillna ! ...  " df1[['path']].merge(df2, 'left').set_index(df1.index).fillna({**df1}) "

Answer (score 1):

Based on the great answer from piRSquared,
The answer I was looking for :

```
df1 = (df1[['path']]
       .merge(df2, 'left')
       .set_index(df1.index)
       .fillna(df1))
```